В ем отличие async await от promise в createAsyncThunk?
Есть 2 кода:
export const checkAuthFun = createAppAsyncThunk(
'user/authorization',    async (_, thunkAPI) => {
    const {data} = await thunkAPI.extra.$authHost.get('/user/auth');
    localStorage.setItem('token', data);
    return data;
},

и
export const checkAuthFun = createAppAsyncThunk(
'user/authorization',     (_, thunkAPI) => {
    thunkAPI.extra.$authHost.get('/user/auth').then(({data}) => {
        localStorage.setItem('token', data);
        return data
    }).catch(({er}) => {
        return er
    })
},)

Первый работает как надо, а второй всегда fulfilled.
Почему ?

Как минимум вы в принципе не возвращаете промис из функции во втором коде
